# Unable to get the entire json response from the RestHandler

Tags: java, json

I am getting the list of all the available categories from a merchant site using their api.The response json string will give all the categories in a single response without page numbers..When I try to convert the json response string into a java object I get.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 11
```

This is what I have done.

```
String jsonResponse = restHandler.executeAPI("taxonomy");
        System.out.println(jsonResponse);

            System.out.println(jsonResponse);


             Gson gson = new Gson();
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(jsonResponse).getAsJsonArray();
```

Can anyone tell me how to get all the categories in a single response .So that I will not get the above exception.

Comment: First of all, check what is returned from the server.

Comment: @pkalinow I ran the url in the browser and got the entire resonse .But when I run the same url using  restHandler.executeAPI() function I dont get the entire response.